# How can I give an SVG document a title, which works the same way as the <title> element in the <head> of an HTML document?

Tags: svg, meta

In an HTML document `<head>`, the `<title>` element declares the human-readable name of the entire document, which then displays in browsers (when hovering over browser tabs etc.) and is understood by user-agents.

How can I, similarly, give an SVG document a top-level title, which fulfils the same meta-data function as an HTML `<title>` and is displayed by browsers and understood by user-agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any web articles / tutorials verifying this, but, as far as I can tell, adding a **meta-title** to an **SVG Document** is entirely straightforward.

Immediately beneath the opening `<svg>` element add an SVG `<title>` element.

That's it.

`<title>` is used much more in SVG, than in HTML, but an un-nested `<title>` as the first element placed at the start of the SVG document will serve as the **meta-title** of the entire SVG document.

**Example:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 1200 1200">

<title>My SVG Document Title Here</title>
<!-- ^^^ SVG Title goes here at the start of the SVG -->

<defs>

  [... SVG DOCUMENT CONTINUES...]
```